# Why can’t a 650w rated UPS can not power my 350w computer on main power failure

Tags: power-supply, ups

I have a computer that could potentially draw 350w on high load. Due to main failures often, I grabbed 1,000va (650w rated) UPS from Emerson. After fully charging the UPS battery, I have done self tests when computer is on idle and load.

- On idle, UPS kept PC alive.
- However when I tried the same test on load (when GPU is running, ups software says 44% load) the UPS fails.

Then I tried same thing on different brand of UPS with almost identical capacity and the same phenomenon occurs. I'm pretty sure my system can not go past 350w of load.

What could be the problem? How can I troubleshoot? Should I place voltage regulator in front of UPS? Could my PSU too sensitive on high loads?

All the UPS’s I tried are line-interactive.

Update: It turns put my PSU cant hold up the system while line-interactive UPS could switch to battery. I bought the new PSU and problem solved.

Comment: I have had a 750VA APC UPS to power my network and main computer for years with no issue.  Is the computer set for 120 Volts and the UPS set to output 120 Volts? Is the UPS output a Sine Wave or a Hash resembling 120 Volts?  Is the computer load larger than you think?  Wattmeter needed.

Comment: What do you mean by "the UPS fails" exactly? Do you mean the computer crashes, shuts down, or reboots when you disconnect the power? If so, how did you determine that was a UPS problem and not a computer power supply problem?

Comment: @John I'm in a eu area, so im dealing with 220V. Computer has 5900x (power limitted to 140w max) and gtx 1070 (power limited to %75). I really dont think i need wattmeter, the components can not possibly pass 400watts, yet calculations of mine and ups software overlaps.

Comment: @DavidSchwarts Computer shut down due to power outage. I yet determined anything i'm trying to troubleshoot the problemn. Also how it could be PSU problem while it works perfectly on main power?

Comment: @incxbxs You are 100% positive the power goes out? How did you determine that? "Also how it could be PSU problem while it works perfectly on main power?" Because it's the PSU's job to hold up the output voltage while the UPS adjusts the output voltage. Some power supplies can't meet the requirements. See [here](https://www.fsp-group.com/en/knowledge-prd-10.html) for more information. If the holding time is less than 16ms (not too uncommon in low end power supplies) the computer can shutdown, crash, or reboot when the UPS engages even if the UPS meets the specifications.

Comment: how it could be PSU problem while it works perfectly on main power?   <--- Check the output of the UPS: Voltage output and if you can determine the waveform.

Comment: @John, unfourtunately i dont have the oscilloscope to check waveform of UPS output.

Comment: What power supply make and model does your computer use? I can check if anyone's measured the hold up time. I had one power supply that would reboot every time I pulled the plug on my UPS. I measured the hold up time and it was, unsurprisingly, not up to specifications. ([Tom's Hardware measured similar issues.](https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/thermaltake-toughpower-grand-rgb-850w-gold-psu,5822-4.html))

Comment: Also, if the UPS units are new, did you ensure the internal batteries are connected?  Remove any tabs. Also you should be able to get an inexpensive Voltmeter and measure the UPS output voltage.

Comment: I read over your question again more carefully. This definitely sounds like a low-quality power supply that can't meet the ATX specification's requirements for output voltage hold up and PWR_OK signal holdup. What's the make and model of the power supply? This is probably not the UPS's fault. Line interactive UPSes typically require 15 ms or so to synchronize and stabilize their output. If the PSU drops either its output voltage or its "power is good" signal in that time, the computer will reboot or shutdown.

Comment: @David Schwartz PSU is almost 10 years old HighPower 750watt bronze active PFC.
However i tried UPS in different system now which uses this ->http://www.highpower-tech.com/Global/file_download.php?type=1&filename=%20Spec%C2%A0&file=3_202009081146410.pdf

In that case, computer did not shutdown on load (around 250w-300w load).
Which i concluded that i need to grap new PSU.

Comment: @John, I own high quality multimeter though yet i need to measure output voltage on load, (because we know it works fine on low loads) which requires some set-up. However it kinda looks like PSU is the usual suspect.

Comment: From what I can tell, that power supply had a decent hold up time when it was new. It's possible its capacitors aged badly, but that's a guess. My first suspicion given your description is still that it's the PSU and I bet a new PSU will make the problem go away. [Capacitor plague](https://hackaday.com/2019/04/12/ask-hackaday-experiences-with-capacitor-failure/) ended in 2007 and your PSU is supposed to have a rubycon capacitor (which would be immune), but I wonder if maybe that's the issue.

Comment: You say the PSU works perfectly on MAINS AC so I took that into account.  I do not know what AC extensions you can set up. If the UPS has two AC UPS sockets plug the PC into one and the digital MM probes into the other (be very careful). Then turn on the PC, apply the load as you did in your post, and then take a note of the UPS voltage.

Comment: @John if i know me correctly, i will short UPS while doing that:) So first, i will try the UPS with new PSU.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz i decided to grap this -> https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/xpg-core-reactor-650w-power-supply-review

Most likely problem will go away. I'll update here tomorrow.

Comment: Put your DMM probes into the UPS socket (one of the sockets) . That will not short the UPS.  It is a test you can do while waiting for a new PSU.

Comment: Do you also run the screen on the UPS? Or does it go dark?